# Memory allocation inside function

Tags: c

The function `pba` should assign to `pointers` variable the pointers in `arr` that are below the average of all the others in `arr`.

This is homework - though I don't have a problem with implementing this, I do feel like stuff are not completely obvious to me
**My my questions are**

1. How can I allocate the memory **inside the function** (instead of outside)?
2. Is my allocation okay? I noticed that if I change the `malloc` line to something like `pointers = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*2);` it still works, but `pointers = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*));` won't work so I guess I have some problem understanding what the size should be in the first place

I debugged it and it seems that the memory is not reachable once I leave the function and it doesn't make sense to me since this is inside the heap memory.

```
void main() {
    int arrSize = 6;
    int arr[6] = {8,4,2,9,5,4};
    int **pointers;
    int resSize, i;
    pointers = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*arrSize);

    pba(arr, 6, pointers, &resSize);
    for (i = 0 ; i < resSize ; i++) {
        printf("%d,",*(*pointers + i));
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

void pba(int* arr, unsigned int size, int ** pointers, int * resSize) {
    int i,j = 0,sum = 0;
    double avg;
    *resSize = 0;

    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    avg = sum/(double)size;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < avg) 
            pointers[(*resSize)++] = &arr[i];       
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to do in the bottom line ?

Comment: Your code would be simplified if you changed `int **pointers` to `int  *pointers`. `pointers` only needs to point to integer variables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You are allocating heap memory inside a function, which is called `main`. You could allocate inside the `pba` function, but the allocated value has to be returned. Or as a return value, then the `int**` can be used, or as a function argument. But in this case You need to pass a pointer to `int**` not just an `int**`. Don't forget to use `free()` to deallocate if the array is not needed anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Just use heap allocation and pointer to pointer to pointer type...

```
void main() {
   ...
   pba(arr, 6, &pointers, &resSize);
   ...
   free(pointers);
}


void pba(int* arr, unsigned int size, int ***pointers, int * resSize) {
   ...
   *pointers = malloc(sizeof(*pointers)*size);
    avg = sum/(double)size;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        if (arr[i] < avg) 
            (*pointers)[(*resSize)++] = &arr[i];       
    }
}
```